# Checkbox rows - slideUp complete issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple divs of 3 checkboxes – each div has a show/hide button (jQuery slideUp) that hides the **'ul.task-list'** to display the H2 heading.

```
<div class="row" id="row-0">
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    
    <h2>Row 0</h2>
    
    <ul class="task-list">
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-0" class="task" value="0" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-1" class="task" value="1" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-2" class="task" value="2" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row-1">
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
    
    <h2>Row 1</h2>
    
    <ul class="task-list">
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-0" class="task" value="0" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-1" class="task" value="1" /></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-2" class="task" value="2" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I call a 'checkTotal' function, and if everything in the row is checked, add the class of "complete" and **slideUp** the UL.

```
let sections = $('.row').map(function() { return this.id }).get(); // gets id of row

const tasksTotal = 3; // the total checkboxes in each row

function checkTotal() {
    sections.forEach(function(i) { // loops section IDs
        let total = $('#'+i+' input:checked').length; // checked in row
        total == tasksTotal ? ($('#'+i).addClass('complete'), $('#'+i+' .task-list').slideUp()) : ($('#'+i).removeClass('complete')); // add class & hide row
    });
}

checkTotal();
```

The issue is, if I click to show row 0 (after complete) and then check anything in row 1 – it will automatically slide row 0 up again – as complete remains true (all items are checked).

I just can't figure out how to separate these, so they act independently and without looping through again.

Comment: can you create a demo code ?

Comment: Have added a CodePen here: https://codepen.io/EP9/pen/wvMPBVw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can passed `this` under your `checkTotal()` function which will be used to check only the checkbox which is check by user.Then we can use `this` to get closest `ul` and loop through only that part where checkbox is located and then to we need to find checkbox length which are checked we can get that using `elem.find("input:checked").length`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings('.task-list').slideToggle();

  });

  const tasksTotal = 3; // the total checkboxes in each row

  function checkTotal(el) {
  //find closest ul
    var elem = jQuery(el).closest(".task-list");
    //loop through it
     elem.each(function() { 
      //get total count of checked input
      let total = elem.find("input:checked").length; 
      console.log(total)
      //apply the same to particular ul 
      total == tasksTotal ? (elem.addClass('complete'), elem.slideUp()) : (elem.removeClass('complete')); 
    });
  }

  $('.task').change(function() {
    checkTotal(this);//passed only the checkbox clicked
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="row-0">
  <div class="options">
    <h2>Row 0</h2>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="task-list" data="abd">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-0" class="task" value="0" /> <label for="task-0-0"> Item 0</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-1" class="task" value="1" /> <label for="task-0-1"> Item 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-0-2" class="task" value="2" /> <label for="task-0-2"> Item 2</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row" id="row-1">
  <div class="options">
    <h2>Row 1</h2>
    <button class="toggle">Toggle</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="task-list">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-0" class="task" value="0" /> <label for="task-1-0"> Item 0</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-1" class="task" value="1" /> <label for="task-1-1"> Item 1</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="task-1-2" class="task" value="2" /> <label for="task-1-2"> Item 2</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```